# How to kill a nodejs process in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill

```
tcp    0     0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      9631/node
```

How do I kill this process in linux(ubuntu)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Port 3000 already in use but it actually isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322089/node-js-port-3000-already-in-use-but-it-actually-isnt)

Answer (score 136):

pkill is the easiest command line utility

```
pkill -f node
```

or

```
pkill -f nodejs
```

whatever name the process runs as for your os

—- update —-
It has been raised that this does not address killing a single node process and instead kills EVERY node process. If this is desired pkill is your tool, otherwise use one of the other accepted answers

Comment: Just the heads up, it will disrupt your Skype, Slack, VSCode, etc. In other words, any program which has fired up nodejs process.

Comment: Great solution to kill all node processes.

Comment: This is a poor solution because the question was how to kill a single Node.js process, but the solution is for killing *every* Node.js process. With Node apps becoming increasing common, the risk of killing something additional that you didn't intend is a possiblity.

Comment: @MarkStosberg agreed, this was a good solution 7 years ago but does not answer the question to a t. I can amend the answer with the caveat that it will kill all node processes

Answer (score 103):

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :'3000'
```

3000 is port i was looking for, 
After first command you will have Process ID for that port

```
kill -9 1192
```

in my case 1192 was process Id of process running on 3000 PORT
use -9 for Force kill the process

Comment: this helped me! somehow this approach gave me the node process ID I was looking for based on the blocked port, rather than `ps aux | grep node` thanks a lot!

Answer (score 47):

if you want to kill a specific node process , you can go to command line route and type:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

to get a list of all node process ids. now you can get your process id(pid), then
do:

```
kill -9 PID
```

and if you want to kill all node processes then do:

```
killall -9 node
```

-9 switch is like end task on windows. it will force the process to end.
you can do:

```
kill -l
```

to see all switches of kill command and their comments.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `killall` command as follows:

```
killall node
```

Answer (score 9):

Run `ps aux | grep nodejs`, find the PID of the process you're looking for, then run `kill` starting with SIGTERM (`kill -15 25239`). If that doesn't work then use SIGKILL instead, replacing `-15` with `-9`.

Comment: Thanks. I used 'node' instead of 'nodejs' then it worked well.

Comment: Interesting... In my case `ps aux | grep nodejs` always returns a single row representing the `grep nodejs` process itself.

Comment: i have node v 16  - the command is "ps aux | grep node" without js sofix

Answer (score 7):

First find the Process ID (PID) associated with the port:

```
lsof -i tcp:5000
```

That displayed for me

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox  4228 ravi  243u  IPv4 484748      0t0  TCP localhost:36216->localhost:5000 (ESTABLISHED)
node    12675 ravi   21u  IPv4 231192      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
node    12675 ravi   24u  IPv4 485739      0t0  TCP localhost:5000->localhost:36216 (ESTABLISHED)
```

then kill the process with :

```
kill -9 12675
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to kill use:
`killall -9 /usr/bin/node`

To reload use:
`killall -12 /usr/bin/node`

Comment: with stubborn multiple node process this work like charm

Answer (score 1):

This command works for me in Mac
`sudo pkill node`