# What are the options for terminating/restarting a react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal

I've installed the [cubejs react dashboard project](https://react-dashboard.cube.dev/overview-and-analytics-backend) and started the app running on port 4000.

The app no longer loads on 4000 and I don't have a terminal in which to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I cant kill the process (I don't have admin rights) and starting the app again says it's already running on 4000. Also it appears the app does not have a 'stop' script provided in package.json.

Is there an npm command to get a live output in a new terminal? Or possibly stop the app via a js script? I've searched quite a bit with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

At what system you operate?

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> - opens new terminal window (Mac)

```
kill -9 <PID> (example : kill -9 4133).
```

References:

[How to kill a nodejs process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649267/how-to-kill-a-nodejs-process-in-linux)

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/

https://superuser.com/questions/451032/how-to-kill-a-process-by-port-on-macos-a-la-fuser-k-9000-tcp

---

You can try execute it from .bat file:

[Kill a Process by Looking up the Port being used by it from a .BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204003/kill-a-process-by-looking-up-the-port-being-used-by-it-from-a-bat)

Comment: I've tried this yet i dont have admin rights so it fails (as stated).